# SQL queries using INSERT, JOIN, and UPDATE based on primary key existence

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, database, razor

I'm trying to execute a try/catch statement using two SQL commands. If a user ID does not yet exist in the table "Leaderboard", I would like to add it, along with their weekly score according to what week it is. In this case, their total score would also be their weekly score. If the user already has weekly scores saved in Leaderboard (which means their user ID exists in it as well), then I would like to add their weekly score according to the week number, then add this score to their running total. The queries are not working and I'm not sure why.

```
var weeknumber = 5; // hard coded only for the Stack question
var weeknum_str = "Week" + weeknumber;

        var insertCommand_leader1 = "INSERT INTO Leaderboard (Id, @0, totalScore) INNER JOIN Scores ON WeekNumber = @1  VALUES (Scores.Id, Scores.WeeklyScore, Scores.WeeklyScore) ";
        var insertCommand_leader2 = "INSERT INTO Leaderboard(Id, @0) INNER JOIN Scores ON WeekNumber = @1 VALUES(Scores.Id, Scores.WeeklyScore) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE @2 = Scores.WeeklyScore AND Scores.totalScore = Scores.totalScore + 10) ";

        try
        {
            db.Execute(insertCommand_leader1, weeknum_str, weeknumber);
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Number == 2627)
            {
                db.Execute(insertCommand_leader2, weeknum_str, weeknumber, weeknum_str);
            }
        }
```

No data goes into the Leaderboard database table. And I'm not getting any errors from MS Visual Studios. I assume it's my SQL logic...

Schemas are:

Leaderboard(Id, Week1, Week2, Week3, Week4, Week5, Week6) with Id as the primary key

Scores(Id, WeekNumber, weeklyScore) with Id and WeekNumber as the primary key

Comment: is your id auto incremental field?Display a clear example here.. i didn't even see that your are opening you connection like con.Open().

Comment: @reds I don't think that's the problem since I have other SQL statements in my code (that also use the ID value) that I'm running before this try/catch method is called. The others areworking fine. I'm working with Razor, so I call `@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity; @using WebMatrix.Data; @using System.Data.SqlClient` at the top of the .cshtml page, then to open my db I say `var db = Database.Open("mydatabase");`

Comment: did you check the content value of your insert?

Comment: @reds it's definitely my syntax. I hard coded the variables and I got a message returned that said there was trouble reading command "INNER." Do you know what could be out of order in the query?

Comment: Your query syntax has a problem..

Comment: what values are you saving in column week1 to 6 in leaderboard? and what's the score table for?

Comment: @CurseStacker saving ints. honestly the score table is a bit pointless here. I last-minute needed to make a page that displayed every week's score in this new leaderboard format to correspond with code someone else had written. I came up with this...  `var insertCommand1 = ("INSERT INTO Leaderboard(Id, Week7) SELECT Id AS s.Id, weeklyScore AS s.Week7 FROM Scores s WHERE s.WeekNumber = @0");
        var insertCommand2 = ("INSERT INTO Leaderboard (Id, Week7) SELECT Id AS Id, weeklyScore AS Week7 FROM Scores WHERE WeekNumber = @0 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Week7 = VALUE(weeklyScore))");`

Comment: @CurseStacker It works fine if I cut off the "on duplicate key" part. I'm getting the error that something is wrong around the word "ON" and I assume it's a renaming / subquery issue. I don't really know where to go from here... Do you think you could help me with the syntax?

Comment: @reds it's a subquery issue. I think I need to rename one of the tables... not sure how to do this correctly though. See my new code above

Comment: Can you populate your leaderboard table and show the sample data.

Comment: @CurseStacker found my problem - sql server doesn't support "on duplicate key". I think from here, I just need to find another way to write my query....

Comment: is this column name "DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"?